# PHP add Value to Variable in Variable before echo

Tags: php, variables, echo

i am looking for a solution:

```
$txt = "Welcome to ".$place." City!";
$place = "New York";
echo $txt; // should be "Welcome to New York City!"
```

The variable "$place" can only be declared after the variable "$txt".
Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: When `$txt` is set, it is concatenating `"Welcome to "`, the value of `$place`, and `" City!"` to form a new string. So no, you cannot. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Can you explain the goal here, your example isn't possible, but I bet whatever you actually trying to achieve is

Comment: You can't define a variable before using it.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. But this is pretty close to your example and works as expected:

```
$txt = "Welcome to %s City!";
$place = "New York";
printf($txt, $place); // should be "Welcome to New York City!"
```

https://3v4l.org/jEQvZ

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly. The string is concatenated using the value of `$place` at the time of assignment so any changes to `$place` will not be reflected in the string. You can emulate something like this by writing a function that will generate the string once you know the place it should reference.

```
function welcome($place) {
    return 'Welcome to '.$place.' City!';
}

$place = 'New York';

echo welcome($place);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.
Just create a placeholder and str_replace it.
Notice I changed `"` to `'`.
If you use `"` it will read $place as a variable. With `'` $place is string and can be replaced later in the code.

```
$txt = 'Welcome to $place City!';
$place = "New York";
echo str_replace('$place', $place, $txt);
```

https://3v4l.org/DVtQa

Comment: @SteveO24 no problem. Feel free to accept the answer that you find the best solution. (Not implying that it's mine, they are all very similar)